# How is JWT related to OAuth?

Tags: oauth, jwt

I recently stumbled upon JSON Web Tokens (JWT), and as far as I have understood it, they are just a compact form of a token that can easily be serialized (as it is JSON).

Now, my question is: Are JWTs related to OAuth in any form, or are they two completely independent concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth2 spec doesn't actually require the use of JWTs, since it treats tokens as opaque, but they are a convenient standard for implementers to use. If you look at the [OpenID Connect Specificiation](http://openid.net/connect/), which builds on top of OAuth2 to provide an authentication system, then you'll find that it does make explicit use of JWTs, for example in the definition of the [ID Token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-messages-1_0.html#id_token).

JWTs can also support signing and encryption in a standard way (see the accompanying [JWE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption-10) and [JWS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-10) specs).